# Filter rows in csv based on custom condition

Tags: python, pandas, filter

Say i have a csv like below

```
+-----+-----------+---------+
| ID  | state     | city    |
+-----+-----------+---------+
| 101 | READY     |         |
| 101 | DELIVERED | NEWYORK |
| 101 | DELIVERED | LONDON  |   
| 102 | READY     |         |
| 102 | DELIVERED | LONDON  |
| 103 | READY     |         |
| 103 | DELIVERED | NEWYORK |
| 104 | READY     |         |
| 104 | DELIVERED | TOKYO   |
| 104 | DELIVERED | PARIS   |
| 105 | DELIVERED | NEWYORK |
+-----+-----------+---------+
```

Now I want ID with State `READY` which has `DELIVERED` as `NEWYORK`.

- Same ID will come multiple times with different state and city.
- Always the `city` for **READY** will be empty
- Always the `city` for **DELIVERED** will have some values.

so here first i want to check the value of column `city` for DELIVERED `state`. If it is NEWYORK then take that ID's READY row. If there is no `READY` row for that then we can ignore *(ID 105 in this example)*

*EXPECTED OUTPUT*

```
+-----+-----------+---------+
| ID  | state     | city    |
+-----+-----------+---------+
| 101 | READY     |         |
| 103 | READY     |         |
+-----+-----------+---------+
```

I have tried using self join in pandas. But i have no idea how to proceed further as i'm new to python. Currently i'm doing this in SQL.

```
import pandas as pd
mydata = pd.read_csv('C:/Mypython/Newyork',encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
NY = pd.merge(mydata,mydata,left_on='ID',right_on='ID',how='inner')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `NEWYORK` condition to get a list of IDs, then use that list to filter.

```
new_york_ids = df.loc[df['city']=='NEWYORK', 'ID']
df[(df['state']=='READY') & (df['ID'].isin(new_york_ids))]

    ID  state  city
0  101  READY  None
5  103  READY  None
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's try `groupby().transform()` to identify those with `NEWYORK` and then boolean indexing:

```
has_NY = df['city'].eq('NEWYORK').groupby(df['ID']).transform('any')

mask = df['state'].eq('READY') & has_NY

df[mask]
```

Output:

```
    ID  state  city
0  101  READY  None
5  103  READY  None
```